# Prove $5a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4ab+2ac$

Tags: inequality

I saw this question recently:

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. Prove $5a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4ab+2ac$.

I feel like this is something with AM-GM inequality. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Muirhead's inequality

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just like [every other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/338209/blastzit?tab=questions), you show no effort whatsoever in attempting to answer it on your own. Asking 'Can anyone help me with it?' is simply not enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that 
$$5a^2+b^2+c^2-4ab-2ac=(2a-b)^2+(a-c)^2\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that:

$4a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2 \geq 4ab+2ac$ By AM-GM inequality.

EDIT:
The reason why I come up with such idea is because $b$ and $c$ in RHS is independent. So $ab$ comes from one AM-GM and $ac$ comes from the other. 
Notice that $4ab = 2\sqrt{4a^2b^2} $ since the $2$ is the constant deriving from AM-GM, one shall find the suitable combination of coefficient of $a^2$ and $b^2$ in LHS, $4 = 2^2$ , one combination is $2a^2$,$2b^2$, but the coefficient of $b^2$ in LHS is 1. So it is in vain, then I try $4a^2$,$b^2$. That works.

Answer (score 3):

The quadratic form $5a^2-4ab+b^2-2ac+c^2$ is associated with the symmetric matrix
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}5 & -2 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
that is a [positive semi-definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) by Sylvester's criterion:
$$ 5>0,\qquad \det\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}>0,\qquad \det(M)=0.$$
It follows that for every $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$,
$$  5a^2-4ab+b^2-2ac+c^2 \geq 0 $$
as wanted, and equality is achieved only by $(a,b,c)=\lambda(1,2,1)$,
 since $\ker(M)$ is generated by $(1,2,1)$.